# table row click event not working

Tags: datatables

Hello I'm new to the JavaScript world. i am pulling data from a database using coldfusion into a dataTable and i would like that when i click on a row in the datatable and event is fired which so that the details of that row can be displayed in divs on the same page.

Below is the code i am using but it is not working, i would appreciate it if someone could give me an example that works

```js
 <script type="text/javascript" class="init">
  $(document).ready( function () {

    var table = $('#expenseList').DataTable();  

    $('#expenseList tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        //var name = $('td', this).eq(0).text();
        var name = table.row( this ).data();
        alert( 'You clicked on '+name+'\'s row' );
    } );        

} );
</script>
```

Comment: what exactly "is not working"? Your code seems to work right away -> **http://jsfiddle.net/y3h9x56u/**

Comment: when i click on a table row, nothing happens. There is not alert fired.

Comment: But the fiddle works, I hope? :) If it works for you too, and I think it should, then I tend to say, that you have some errors elsewhere in the code, causing the click handler never to be initialised.

Comment: i have no errors in the code. Here is the entire code, without the js libraries.

Comment: @Arthur Does the fiddle work for you

Comment: No the fiddle doesn't work for me